# Fix "the command get is not currently available" in CS6

Tags: adobe-photoshop, photoshop-scripting, javascript

I want use Photoshop CS6 for batch editing **because it is lite and can be used in sandboxie software**.
following script is fully execute in the latest version of Photoshop (2023):

```
#target photoshop

/* Check for selection - from jazz-y */
var selectionBounds = null;
try {
    selectionBounds = activeDocument.selection.bounds
} catch (e) {}
if (selectionBounds) {

        /* Start Process selected layers - from jazz-y */
        var s2t = stringIDToTypeID;
        (r = new ActionReference()).putProperty(s2t('property'), p = s2t('targetLayersIDs'));
        r.putEnumerated(s2t('document'), s2t('ordinal'), s2t('targetEnum'));
        var lrs = executeActionGet(r).getList(p),
            sel = new ActionReference();
        for (var i = 0; i < lrs.count; i++) {
            sel.putIdentifier(s2t('layer'), p = lrs.getReference(i).getIdentifier(s2t('layerID')));
            (r = new ActionReference()).putIdentifier(s2t('layer'), p);
            (d = new ActionDescriptor()).putReference(s2t("target"), r);
            executeAction(s2t('select'), d, DialogModes.NO);
        /* End Process selected layers - from jazz-y */

        /* Clear selected layers */
        try {
            activeDocument.selection.clear()
        } catch (e) {}
    }

} else {
    alert("This script requires a selection!");
}
```

**but when i run above script in CS6 i get following error:**

[image]

how to fix this error in CS6?

Comment: Have I got deja vu… again? This is one of the few stacks I can't see deleted questions [though my browser remembers the links], but I do seem to recall this - https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/161604/remove-command-delete-is-not-currently-available-from-photoshop-script

Comment: @Tetsujin that question solved by another script. this question is for cs6!!

Comment: If it was solved why did you delete it rather than accept an answer to it? If it had downvotes, which I can't recall, then you damage your ability to continue to ask questions more by deletion. No-one outside SE staff knows the exact rules for the automatic question ban, but they're triggered by downvotes & deletions.

Comment: @Tetsujin because after get most views nobody answer to it and script that i used not related to that question

Comment: Ya know... if you were to describe.... "I have `A`... I need to get to `B`" .... you *may* find you get better answers. Troubleshooting script error after script error after script error... is typically **not** what designers do. Across *all* your questions... you have yet to describe the *entire problem* you are attempting to solve. Even when asked. As for this question... if a feature isn't supported in CS6 there's **nothing** you can do to add that feature.

Answer (score 0):

If a feature or command is **not** available in an older (legacy) version of **any** Adobe application, there is **nothing** a user can do in order to add said missing feature/command.

This is *why* Adobe releases updates to their applications.. to *add features/commands*.

In some instances, it *may* be possible to alter a workflow and achieve similar results *without* using said feature/command. But that's not a "given". In some instances one needs to *entirely re-think* how to solve an issue if an application does not have a necessary feature.

---

In short... Users **can not** add features which are present in the latest releases of Photoshop to Photoshop CS6. That would defeat the purpose of Adobe releasing updates to Photoshop (and charging a fee for said updates).

Comment: That said, it could help if they checked the API documentation for CS6

Comment: @Yorik wouldn’t really, this code is ActionManager code that’s not covered in the API docs. There was indeed something particular about getting selected layers in CS6 with this function but.. it’s a 11yo software and OP is too obnoxious

Comment: @SergeyKritskiy I vaguely recall manipulating the recorded scripts being pretty opaque

Answer (score -1):

I don't know why everyone who sees the post gives a negative score! And this will cause my post to be deleted!
I found solution for this problem. following is edited script that works fine with CS6!

```
var nn = 0;
try { activeDocument.backgroundLayer } catch(e) { nn = 1; }

var s2t = stringIDToTypeID;
(r = new ActionReference()).putProperty(s2t('property'), p = s2t('targetLayers'));
r.putEnumerated(s2t('document'), s2t('ordinal'), s2t('targetEnum'));
var lrs = executeActionGet(r).getList(p),
    sel = new ActionReference();

for (var i = 0; i < lrs.count; i++) {
    sel.putIndex(s2t('layer'), p = lrs.getReference(i).getIndex(i));
    (r = new ActionReference()).putIndex(s2t('layer'), p+nn);
    (d = new ActionDescriptor()).putReference(s2t("target"), r);
    executeAction(s2t('select'), d, DialogModes.NO);


        /* Clear selected layers */
        try {
            activeDocument.selection.clear()
        } catch (e) {}
    }
```